# Would a HTML encryption be a viable way to hide javascript variables?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a project and I know that Javascript is client-side and accessible to everyone. I'm wondering how safe/dangerous it is if I use an online HTML encrypter. I tried de-crypting it and it's still looks jibberish and I can't find the secret-key.

Thanks.

Note : I'm trying to store google recaptcha secret key. I don't want to use PHP to POST the token, which means my secret key is publicly accessible through

```
fetch(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=xxxxxxx)
```

TL;DR : How safe is HTML encryption for a secret key that's stored in javascript?

Comment: Completely unsafe. It's not encryption but obfuscation.

Comment: Why are you trying to store your secret key in public? That's kind of where things break down. The only way to keep code and keys safe from prying eyes on the web, is to not put them on the web in the first place, so keep your secrets where you control them, e.g. on your server. Whether you want to or not, tokens are the safe way to work with authenticate services without exposing your secret keys, because tokens can trivially revoked. Just use them?

Comment: Remember this concept: "Nothing is safe in client-side". Just one of the reasons it doesn't work is that even if you do make the encryption (which is merely an obfuscation), that secret key can still be inspected through developer console in the network tab when a request is made.

Comment: I guess I'll have to use PHP, thanks everyone!